# Ruby function for putting string in parentheses

Tags: ruby, string

Is there any function to place parentheses on both sides of a string as with `str` in the following?

```
str = ' ( '.concat(str.concat(' ) '))
```

Comment: `str = " ( #{str} ) "`

Comment: The esoteric variant: `str = [' ( ', ' ) '].join(str)`.

Comment: `str = ' ( ' << str << ' ) '`

Comment: Using a template string: `str = ' ( %s ) ' % str`

Comment: Or `str.prepend(' ( ').concat(' ) ')` which changes `str` in-place, making the assignment superfluous.

Comment: `str.sub(/.+/, ' ( \0 ) ')` or use `sub!` for in-place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use string interpolation:

```
str = " ( #{str} ) "
```

Some other options might be:

```
str = ' ( ' +  str + ' ) '
str = [' ( ', str, ' ) '].join
```

Comment: String interpolation seems a good option. Other two options will produce exception, if str is nil

Comment: Yes, that is true when `str`  might be `nil` then the last two version will not work. I would prefer string interpolation (the first option) for various reasons: able to handle `nil`, performances (if I remember correctly) and most important: it is easy to read and to understand.

Comment: `join` gracefully handles `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

I preferred String interpolation, this is just for alternate solution **[String#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-insert)**

```
> "Gagan Gami".insert(0, '(').insert(-1, ')')
#=> "(Gagan Gami)"
# OR
> "()".insert(1, "Gagan Gami")
#=> "(Gagan Gami)"
```

---

> Ruby function for putting string in parentheses

```
> parentheses = "()"
> str = "Gagan Gami"
> parentheses.insert(1, str)
#=> "(Gagan Gami)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you'll need often you can also monkey patch the string class, and would be prefered to use string interpolation.

```
class String
  def in_parens
    "( #{self} )"
  end
end

puts 'foo'.in_perens 
#=> ( foo )
puts ''.in_perens 
#=> ( )

require 'date'
puts Date.today.to_s.in_parens 
#=> ( 2018-10-09 )

date = Date.today.to_s.in_parens
puts date.in_parens
#=> ( ( 2018-10-09 ) )
```

Well you get the idea